# how to get values from 2 textBoxes in a UiApp handler event?

Tags: textbox, handler

I'm new to app script, so I have tried to create a form with several text boxes that input values to allow the computation of a final value, when the user clicks in the form button.

First, I have tried to user the standard code, but then realized I'm allowed to pass only 1 textbox value at a time and I need several:

```
app.createButton('Compute').addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("btComputeOnClick").addCallbackElement(txtValue1));
```

Then I tried to use the form/flow createSubmitButton() but once the event is processed, the whole form contents is cleared, and I need to update only the calculated value in one form TextBox, to allow the user to change previous values and compute again.

How can I pass several TextBox values to my processing event handler, while retaining the form contents and update a single TextBox?

Answer (score 0):

After searching on other posts, I found the solution here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/building-sites-app-part1#section4

Based on that post, I have to use a panel to hold all widgets that I need to access in my handler function!

Thanks anyway,
mdias